# Stuttering when using SurfaceTexture and Camera (Android 4.0 ICS)

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera

I have noticed an interesting bug when using `SurfaceTexture` with the `Camera`.

If I setup a `SurfaceTexture`, pass it a valid `OpenGL` texture and pass that into the `Camera`, everything works great.  I can then swap out the pixel shader with a simple shader and all still works great.  But if I swap out the pixel shader with a more complex shader the framerate drops and stuttering appears.

What seems to be happening is that a frame is getting processed out of order.  After some hypothesizing I wondered if the hardware was being sent too much to do.  After trying a number of things I found that if I just slept the gl processing thread for around 75 milliseconds or so the framerate jumped back up and the stuttering disappeared.

This is an okay hack for now, but I worry that value is just an arbitrary guess based on my shader, and that it may change with other shaders or other phones.  My question is: Is it possible to know when it is safe to send another frame down to OpenGL without over-taxing the system?  (Or is something else going on here?)

I have tried using `glFinish`, and `glFlush` but neither of these helped.  I wondered if that was because the camera uses samplerExternalOES and somehow that effects it?

Note: If I run the same `OpenGL` code using a `SurfaceView` instead I don't get any stuttering.  Of course the performance isn't as good so that may be the reason it doesn't.

Comment: ``If I setup a TextureView, pass it a valid OpenGL texture and pass that into the Camera`` could you be a bit more specific what you're doing exactly? If I read documentation correctly TextureView does not take texture as parameter but creates SurfaceTexture for you. Also changing shaders is something I can't find in the documentation but TextureView seems more of a 'static' HW accelerated View in that sense.

Comment: Right.  My mistake everywhere I said TextureView I meant to say SurfaceTexture.  I'll update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Note glFinish() and glFlush() are currently no-ops on Android.
See frameworks/base/opengl/libagl/state.cpp in the android source tree.

The most useful thing I could find to do with a similar situation was to queue the work, and then hook onDrawFrame() to finish the work on the assumption that the previous ops were finished.

I.e. I was rendering into a texture, and then calling glReadPixels on the texture.
Calling glReadPixels directly incurred a multi-millisecond sleep while it awaited the completion of rendering. Instead, I kicked off the render, and then in onDrawFrame() I called glReadPixels. This (usually!) resulted in glReadPixels running immediately.